# How to verify tomcat is started successfully using batch script?

Tags: shell, batch-file, spring-batch-admin

Have prepared a batch script to automate the build process. Was successfully able to figure out the success and failures of build using ant in batch script (%ERRORLEVEL%), accordingly displayed the message box with proper message.

Based on ant success have executed command to startup tomcat server, but how do i come to know in batch script whether it has been started or failed?

Your help is highly appreciated.!!

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe not a great question for stackoverflow... Would need to know the environment to try and answer.

Comment: Assuming that you set it up to run as a service you can use the [SC](https://ss64.com/nt/sc.html) command to query the service status.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@echo off

call :is_running svchost.exe
echo %errorlevel%

call :is_running explorer.exe
echo %errorlevel%

call :is_running tomcat.exe
echo %errorlevel%

exit /b   

:is_running
tasklist^
 /fi "IMAGENAME eq %~1"^
 /fi "STATUS eq running"^
 /nh 2>nul | find "%~1" >nul || exit /b 1
exit /b 0
```

This calls a label named `is_running` and runs `tasklist` to find the `ImageName` running. If not running then errorlevel 1 is set. Added a few processes to test to display if it is working well.

Use the command `tasklist /?` for help.